# I want to get database based on user id by a get method using esql in IBM app connect, so how can I do that

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

how to access the query param by esql?

```
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.customer_details[] = 
  PASSTHRU('SELECT* FROM customers.customer WHERE customer_id =InputRoot.JSON.Data.customer_id');
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.customer_details[]= PASSTHRU('SELECT * FROM customers.customer WHERE customer_id =InputRoot.JSON.Data.customer_id');
```

Comment: The two SET statements are identical?

Comment: no that was my trail